# Why am I getting a segmentation fault when using realloc()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

This small testing program is reading strings from the command line, and I'm getting a seg fault. Can anyone help me?

I also want to ask about how is `realloc()` different from `malloc()`? I mean I think `realloc()` is way smarter so why do we even need `malloc()`? And for `malloc()` I know we have to copy the strings and `malloc()` into the new memory, but can anyone gives me an example of that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//reading the string from the command line
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char** inputStrings;


  int i;
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
    inputStrings=realloc(*inputStrings,i*sizeof(argv[i]));

    inputStrings[i-1]=argv[i];

  }
  for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++){

    printf("what is in the address: %s\n",inputStrings[i]);
  }

  free(inputStrings);
  return 0;



}
```

Comment: One question per question. First one answered. For others, read the respective manual pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char **inputStrings = NULL;

    int i;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        inputStrings=realloc(inputStrings, i*sizeof(argv[i]));//check omitted
        inputStrings[i-1]=argv[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++){
        printf("what is in the address: %s\n", inputStrings[i]);
    }
    free(inputStrings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `realloc` is not required for each elements because the required size is seen by `argc` in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to allocate memory to `char** inputStrings;`

To solve,

1. allocate memory to `inputStrings` and `inputStrings[i]`. [`malloc()`/ `calloc()`]

or,

2. allocate memory to `inputStrings` and set `inputStrings[i]` to `NULL` before `realloc()`.

Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) of `realloc()`.

<sup>Note: Please learn to use a debugger, like `gdb`. It's *really* helpful to pinpoint errors like the above ones.</sup>

---

Edit:

```
inputStrings=realloc(*inputStrings,i*sizeof(argv[i]));
```

is also wrong concept. You have to allocate memory to `inputStrings` and `inputStrings[i]` seperately. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257774/2173917) for some help regarding this.

Comment: Just to add to this, even with this, the type of allocation in the OP's code `inputStrings=realloc(*inputStrings,i*sizeof(argv[i]));` doesn't make sense so that also needs to be fixed

Comment: @Gopi Right. Updating.

Answer (score 2):

you should allocate the  memory for that `char** inputString`. using the `malloc` or `calloc` first.

```
inputstring = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

Then you should allocate the memory for each position with in the looping

```
inputString[i] = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

after that only you are able to reallocate the memory using `realloc`.