# Segmentation fault when using malloc with double pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, stack-overflow

This code doesn't work and I don't know why, I used everything exactly as my professor told us and I think it should work, why does compiler throw Segmentation fault(core dumped) exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    char *chr;
    char pchr;
    scanf("%s", chr);
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    char **table = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    char *chr2 = chr;
}
```

this is only part of my program but when I run only this code compiler throws an exception. It doesn't even scan an `n` number it only scans `char` and then throws an exception. Thank you for answers.

Comment: The pointer chr has inderterminate value. As result the program has undefined behavior due to the statement scanf("%s", chr);.

Comment: If you enable warnings your compiler should tell you something along the lines of "Using uninitialized variable chr".

Comment: Scant reads stdin and stores what matches the pattern(format) in the memory which chr points at. Which is undef.

Answer (score 0):

As you obviously noticed, the issues are here:

```
char *chr;
scanf("%s", chr);
```

What `scanf` does is place the string it reads from console input into some memory address pointed to by `chr`. As some have already mentioned, your problem here is two-fold

1. `chr` is not initialized, thus giving you undefined behaviour as that variable has an indeterminate value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368/7159784) for info on why this is.
2. `chr` has to point to some allocated memory. This can be done in a couple ways, 1) By using a `char[]` or allocating memory with `malloc` and friends.

So there are two way you can go about it:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 50
char chr[BUFFERSIZE] = {'\0'};
scanf("%s", chr);
```

**OR**

```
char* chr = calloc(BUFFERSIZE, sizeof(char));
scanf("%s", chr);
free(chr);
chr = NULL;
```

Next, this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
char **table = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257774/7159784) to see how you would approach allocating a pointer list.